# How to setup Laravel Mix SASS reloading

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, webpack, livereload

How to setup the Laravel Mix on `version 5.4` to do `css` livereloading whenever the `sass` files get compiled? All the tutorials I found are relating to older versions.

I have installed the `node` modules, and I am running the watch by `npm run watch`, as stated on the tutorial https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix#sass. So far the `webpack.mix.js` is as follows:

```
const { mix } = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Comment: As stated here: 
`https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/elixir/live-reload-alternative-54`
You need to look for `Webpack-live-reload` and not `Laravel-mix` live reload. 

This might help you to get started, but not tested: `https://gist.github.com/hailwood/82242c08807f1939fc90f60c92a476cf`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how to configure Webpack LiveReload for Laravel >=5.4 and Laravel.mix https://komelin.com/articles/configuring-webpack-livereload-laravelmix

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting the following error ` node node_modules/cross-env/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

module.js:472
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\xampp\htdocs\tamilserials\node_modules\cross-env\bin\cross-env.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
`

Comment: Try to delete node_modules folder and run `npm install` to reinstall all project dependencies.